# Nginx CentOS 7 PHP-FPM 7 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm, gateway, 502

I have configured Nginx, PHP-FPM 7 on CentOS 7.  I am now having a 502 error.

In www.conf:
user and group are nginx.

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

In `/var/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf`:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server  unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name server.com;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/docroot;
    include /var/www/docroot/nginx.conf.sample;
```

php-fpm status:

```
php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-12-18 15:43:40 EST; 4h 21min ago
 Main PID: 5958 (php-fpm)
   Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 5, Requests: 0, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/php-fpm.service
 ├─5958 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
           ├─5959 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5960 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5961 php-fpm: pool www
           ├─5962 php-fpm: pool www
           └─5963 php-fpm: pool www
```

So it seems as though php-fpm is listening.  Yet, still bad gateway.
New to this setup, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Checking your logs is the obvious first step.

Comment: ```listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock``` and ```server  unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;``` must point to the same socket

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix `upstream` value for nginx, it should be pointed to socket defined in `listen` directive of php-fpm

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server  unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
}
```